# Using tilde "~" for the Storyboard names in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, ios-universal-app, tilde

Is it officially supported to use "~" for the Storyboard names for automatic form factor recognition?

```
HomeView~ipad.storyboard
HomeView~iphone.storyboard
```

I know it works if used like that but I want to make sure Apple officially supports this convention for the Storyboards specifically.
I've noticed that by default Xcode templates for the new Universal application are using "_" underscore not "~" tilde for the form factored Storyboards, which then requires some logic in the code to recognize the form factor and use appropriate storyboard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's supported; it's part of resource-loading generally, and a storyboard is a resource.

Note that in iOS 8 you will use a single storyboard for your universal app and this entire issue will go away.

Comment: Any "official" resources to support that, please?

Comment: For example: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AccessingaBundlesContents/AccessingaBundlesContents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH104-SW7